# Combining array_keys and array_values to original array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a method that inserts data into a table using an associative array that looks like this:

```
array(
    "col1" => "value1",
    "col2" => "value2",
    "col3" => "value3",
);
```

If I use `array_keys()` and `array_values()` on the array passed in can I guarantee that the first item in each set, match the original array passed in?

```
// Note: validation excluded
$keys   = array_keys($data);   // $data is the array passed in
$values = array_values($data);
$q      = array_pad(array(), count($data), "?");

$this->query("insert into `$this->table` (`" . implode("`,`", $keys) . "`) values (" . implode(",", $q) . ")", $values);
```

So, with that, can I guarantee that `$keys[1]` and `$values[1]` are the same key and value from the original array, or is it possible that they could be `col3` and `value1`?

Another way to say it, if i use `array_combine($keys, $values)` will I get the original array `key => value` pair back (item order excluded)?

I am worried that if this doesn't do what I am thinking that `value2` may go into `col3` instead of `col2` or something like that....

Comment: Why don't you use `foreach`?

Comment: I use foreach for this.

Comment: I could, but this just looks cleaner...

Comment: @LeviMorrison I am using PDO, so if there is injection it would be PDO's fault.

Comment: @PaulCrovella yes they will be the same or yes the will possibly mismatch?

Comment: @RyanNaddy I somehow missed the prepared statement part, mostly because you appear to be writing some kind of abstraction over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the functions `array_keys($data)` and `array_values($data)` will return the data in the original order.

A search of the PHP reference site for the `array_combine()` method will show that the method combines the arrays in their original order as well.

For example,

```
array(
    'red' => 5,
    'green' => 10,
    'blue' => 15
);
```

would be split into the keys array:

```
array(
    'red',
    'green',
    'blue'
);
```

and the values array:

```
array(
    5,
    10,
    15
);
```

Combining these arrays with array_combine($keys, $values) would give you the array:

```
array(
    'red' => 5,
    'green' => 10,
    'blue' => 15
);
```

**Examples from PHP site**

[Array Keys PHP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
<?php
    $array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
    print_r(array_keys($array));

    $array = array("color" => array("blue", "red", "green"),
           "size"  => array("small", "medium", "large"));
    print_r(array_keys($array));
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => color
)
Array
(
    [0] => color
    [1] => size
)
```

[Array Values PHP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
<?php
    $array = array("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");
    print_r(array_values($array));
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => XL
    [1] => gold
)
```

[Array Combine PHP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
<?php
    $a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
    $b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
    $c = array_combine($a, $b);

    print_r($c);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by quoting the relevant portions of those pages, rather than just linking. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Okay, thanks! It looks like it is basically guaranteed. At Least according to the "Duplicate" link.

Comment: No problem, @RyanNaddy!
Thanks for the suggestions for improvement, @LeviMorrison, I added some snippets from the link that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Using a foreach loop you will always be sure that the key/value pair matches. As other's have pointed out you should at least escape the input values and/or use PDO for insertion. I haven't included that below since that was not your actual question.

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
//add keys to key array
$keys[]=$k;
//add values to value array
$vals[]=$v;
}
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP (and future visitors to SO) why you did what you did.